# Performing movements/motions in order to show-off or attract audience

Tags: word-request

I was wondering what do you normally call performing some movements / motions which attracts the audience by a motorcycle / bicycle / car / plane or the movements in martial arts (like karate) or in soccer when a player is doing with a ball? 
Please have a look on the following images and let me know which single verb is used to describe all these actions?

[image]
[image][image][image][image][image]

I wonder which type of movements / motions they are doing?

Comment: I'd just call them all *[acrobatic] **stunts*** (perhaps [***aerobatic stunt***](https://www.redletterdays.co.uk/experience/ref/xsfia/an-aerobatic-flight) for the plane). "Stunts" are nearly always performed in order to impress an audience.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers, just do you **perform** acrobatic stunts **with** a motorcycle/car/plane? Does a soccer/karate player **perform** acrobatic stunts too?

Comment: One way to see how a word is used is to look at the [dictionary examples](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stunt). One is "perform a stunt" because after all, it **is** a performance. Note you can perform stunts **on** a motorcycle, like the way you ride it.

Comment: in the first picture, the standard idiom is to "pull a wheelie" (sometimes "pop a wheelie") although the stunt looks slightly more involved than just a wheelie.

Comment: @A-friend: I'd probably say *[acrobatic] stunts **on** a motorcycle*, but it's not really a context where it's meaningful to say only one preposition works (besides which you could just go for the prepositionless "noun adjunct" usage ***motorcycle** stunts*). And for a ***car*** or ***plane***, the main choices would be ***with*** or ***in*** (not ***on***).

Comment: Thank you again @FumbleFingers. +1 Just what about the soccer and karate players? Does the soccer player perform acrobatic stunts **with** a ball?

Comment: Specifically for the "soccer player", there's this from Wikipedia: [***Keepie uppie, keep-ups** or **kick-ups** is the skill of juggling **with** an association football using feet, lower legs, knees, chest, shoulders, and head, without allowing the ball to hit the ground. It is similar to **Kemari**, a game formerly practiced in the Japanese imperial court.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepie_uppie) I'd never heard of ***Kemari*** until just now - I just found it when I Googled **acrobatic stunts keepie uppie** looking for any related terms.

Comment: Bear in mind that *most people don't do, and rarely see* such activities (that's why they're ***stunts*** - they attract attention because they're "unusual"). So the general population don't necessarily have a well-developed vocabulary or syntax for the context. Me, for example, I wouldn't know what to call what the martial arts guy is holding (and he might even be offended if I called it a ***stick*** or a ***snooker cue**!* :) But yeah - in principle they're all doing stunts ***with** ["props"]*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "**what is performing something to attract attention or to show-off**" and not the individual stunt names:

flaunt: Display (something) ostentatiously, especially in order to provoke envy or admiration or to show defiance.[Source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/flaunt)

As mentioned in the original comments these would be considered stunts, the soccer player and martial artist aren't specifically performing stunts as what they are doing are routine exercises for their sport. They would only be considered stunts or showing off their acrobatics if they were performed outside of their normal venue (gymnasium or soccer field). Which they both appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

[Perform](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perform)

> to give a performance : PLAY

This is an intransitive verb, so you just say that the motorcycle rider/karate artist/juggler/whatever performed.

Answer (score -3):

There is no verb that applies to all those pictures.

But pictures #1, 3, 5, and 6 show someone with an arm or both arms fully extended.